# How to burn a .bin image to a USB flash drive in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media, rufus

I’m running Windows 7 and have a .bin file that I need to burn to a USB flash drive. It’s the Chromebook recovery image for my [HP Chromebook 14-q063cl](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04015753).

So, as far as i know, the dd command isn't available, for Windows.

I have Rufus version 3.15, which does not support .bin extensions, and the download pages state that they support .iso but I don’t see support for .bin

PowerISO supports .bin files, but will only write to CD/DVD, not a USB flash drive.

What am I missing? How can I burn this .bin to my USB flash drive?

Answer (score 3):

> I have Rufus version 3.15, which does not support .bin extensions

1. The latest version of Rufus is 3.20, so your version is quite old
2. It's not because `.bin` is not in the list of extensions Rufus will list by default as `dd` images that Rufus doesn't support it. Just choose `*.*` (i.e. all files) and if your `.bin` is really a `dd` bootable image, Rufus will happily pick it up and write it to your media as if you had been using `dd`.

Comment: thank you.  yes, rufus will pick it up as dd

Answer (score 1):

There are many programs out there to do this.

I myself use the [Win32 Disk Imager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) which is free and GPL/open source.

If you use the OpenFileDialog where it says "Image File", change the mask to star.star (as opposed to .img) and pick your .bin file.  Otherwise, simply paste in the path to your bin file.

I have used this many times for stuff I needed to do against embedded devices.  I believe that it will work for you.

Comment: cool.  a new toy that i've never heard of before.  thank you

Answer (score -1):

[ImgBurn](https://www.imgburn.com/) (freeware) can do exactly that!

It's latest release was also from 2012 so it will absolutely work on Windows 7.

Comment: thank you.  i've used imgburn before.  i'll take a look at it again
btw. stack overflow won't let me vote so i didn't downvote you